# How do I transfer data from one Observer to another?

Tags: event-observer

I need to pass the value of a variable from one Observer that monitoring the cms_controller_router_match_before event to an Observer that monitoring the cms_page_render event. How can this be done without using Session Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Magento 2 Registry & Register are used to store and retrieve data.**

Link : https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-registry-register.html#how-to-get-and-set-custom-attribute-in-registry--register

Answer (score 0):

Magento with cache can also be used to store and retrieve data.

**Reference:**
https://inchoo.net/magento-2/cache/how-to-save-custom-data-cache-magento-2/